# Python Pandas Memory Error during Drop

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a df of 825468 rows.
I am performing this over it.

```
  frame = frame.drop(frame.loc[(
            frame['RR'].str.contains(r"^([23])[^-]*-\1[^-]*$")), 'RR'].str.replace("[23]([^-]*)-[23]([^-]*)", r"\1-\2").isin(
             series1.str.replace("1([^-]*)-1([^-]*)", r"\1-\2"))[lambda d: d].index)
```

where

```
  series1 = frame.loc[frame['RR'].str.contains("^1[^-]*-1"), 'RR']
```

So what it does it

prepares a series of where `RR` has value like `1abc-1bcd` and then if in frame there is an `RR` like `2abc-2bcd` which after replacement becomes `abc-bcd` and its there in series as well after replacement,its dropped.

But it gives Memory Error.Is there a more efficient way to perform the same.

For ex.

if in a df ..

```
     RR
0    2abc-2abc
1    1abc-1abc
2    3abc-3abc
3    2def-2def
4    3def-3def
5    def-dfd
6    sdsd-sdsd
7    1def-1def
```

Then from this frame `2abc-2abc` and `3abc-3abc` should be dropped,as after removing 2,3 it becomes `abc-abc` and when we remove `1` from `1abc-1abc` it also is `abc-abc`.`2def-2def` should not be dropped as there is no `1def-1def`

Output:

```
     RR
0    1abc-1abc
1    def-dfd
2    sdsd-sdsd
3    1def-1def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
          RR
0  2abc-2abc
1  3abc-3abc
2  2def-2def
3  3def-3def
4    def-dfd
5  sdsd-sdsd
6  1def-1def
7    abc-abc
8    def-def

In [177]: df[['d1','s','s2']] = df.RR.str.extract(r'^(?P<d1>\d+)(?P<s1>[^-]*)-\1(?P<s2>[^-]*)', expand=True)

In [178]: df
Out[178]:
          RR   d1    s   s2
0  2abc-2abc    2  abc  abc
1  3abc-3abc    3  abc  abc
2  2def-2def    2  def  def
3  3def-3def    3  def  def
4    def-dfd  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  sdsd-sdsd  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  1def-1def    1  def  def
7    abc-abc  NaN  NaN  NaN
8    def-def  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [179]: df.s += df.pop('s2')

In [180]: df
Out[180]:
          RR   d1       s
0  2abc-2abc    2  abcabc
1  3abc-3abc    3  abcabc
2  2def-2def    2  defdef
3  3def-3def    3  defdef
4    def-dfd  NaN     NaN
5  sdsd-sdsd  NaN     NaN
6  1def-1def    1  defdef
7    abc-abc  NaN     NaN
8    def-def  NaN     NaN

In [181]: result = df.loc[~df.s.isin(df.loc[df.d1 == '1', 's']) | (~df.d1.isin(['2','3'])), 'RR']

In [182]: result
Out[182]:
0    2abc-2abc
1    3abc-3abc
4      def-dfd
5    sdsd-sdsd
6    1def-1def
7      abc-abc
8      def-def
Name: RR, dtype: object
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [171]: df
Out[171]:
          RR
0  2abc-2abc
1  1abc-1abc
2  3abc-3abc
3  2def-2def
4  3def-3def
5    def-dfd
6  sdsd-sdsd
7  1def-1def
8    abc-abc
```

NOTE: I have intentionally added 8`th` row: `abc-abc`, which should NOT be dropped (if i understood your question correctly)

**Solution 1:** using `.str.replace()` and `drop_duplicates()` methods:

```
In [178]: (df.sort_values('RR')
     ...:    .RR
     ...:    .str.replace("[23]([^-]*)-[23]([^-]*)", r"1\1-1\2")
     ...:    .drop_duplicates()
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[178]:
1    1abc-1abc
7    1def-1def
8      abc-abc
5      def-dfd
6    sdsd-sdsd
Name: RR, dtype: object
```

**Solution 2:** using `.str.replace()` and `.str.contains()` methods and boolean indexing:

```
In [172]: df.loc[~df.sort_values('RR')
     ...:           .RR
     ...:           .str.replace("[23]([^-]*)-[23]([^-]*)", r"_\1-_\2")
     ...:           .str.contains(r"^_[^-]*-_")]
     ...:
Out[172]:
          RR
1  1abc-1abc
5    def-dfd
6  sdsd-sdsd
7  1def-1def
8    abc-abc
```

NOTE: you may want to replace `'_'` with another symbol(s), which will never occur in the `RR` column

Comment: @vks, you mean changing `'\d+'` to `'[123]+'` wouldn't work properly (as you need)?

Comment: yes as the sequence is not defined....`1abc-1abc` should not get deleted.if it comes after `2abc-2abc` it will get deleted too rt

Comment: have not tested yet.....but looks good...no need of additional series ... But sort of 800000 rows .... That should not result in memoryerror

Comment: Also I think if 1abc-1abc is not in frame it will still replace 2abc-2abc to 1abc-1abc rt ?

Comment: @vks, what about "solution 2" - does it work properly?

Comment: no it wont..suffers from the same problem :) guess will have to stick with my own solution  :)

Comment: @vks, we shouldn't give up that easily! Are those digits `1`,`2`,`3` are always the same digit for one row or is it possible to have something like: `1abc-2abc`. And what about the text part - is it always the same or it can differ like: `1abc-1xyz`?

Comment: It can differ and the same rules apply to those.`2cd-2bc` will get removed if `1cd-1bc` is there

Comment: what about the digits - can they differ within one row like: `1abc-2abc`?

Comment: @vks, can you check UPDATE2 - whether it works properly and whether it's OK in terms of memory usage?